Cohen-Macaulay nonlocal rings implications
I mostly work with local or graded commutative rings, so I have some elementary questions when it comes to nonlocal commutative rings (associative + has 1).
So a commutative ring is Cohen-Macaulay if its localization at every prime (maximal) ideal is Cohen-Macaulay. My question is: Does it imply that all minimal primes are of the same height? And does it imply any other properties?
My intuitive is that it should not imply unmixedness. It is hard to come up with a counterexample. That example may be a ring with 2 minimal primes of different heights, and 2 maximal ideals which contain those separately. So the localization would only have 1 minimal prime each. I feel like it is possible to create a ring that convoluted.
Thank you in advance

Isn’t a minimal prime always of height $0$?
